# Is it possible to get page rendering result programmatically ?

Tags: presentation

I need to get all HTML page content that sitecore generate for an page item. But I need to do it programmatically just for some special tests. 
I can of course just use URL but it is not good for me.
Does LayoutDefinition should work for it ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the different renderings on the different pages?

Comment: no I need get result of rendering, page that end -user could open

Comment: So you mean, when before the page loads you retrieve the different components that will be rendered on the page? Sorry but I am a bit confused of the requirement. If possible, can you share an example to illustrate it

Comment: I spent hours looking at this because the accepted solution **does not return any presentation details** of the item. I implemented this in my project and am calling the extended method directly in my code. https://jeffdarchuk.com/2015/10/18/render-item-to-string-mvc/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think AlokBhatt's method is a good start, though I would make use of pipelines throughout. I think this is a better solution because it doesn't involve trying to parse presentation details, and should handle personalization and other Sitecore features. Here's an example that works for me:

```
public string RenderItem(string itemPath)
{

    var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemPath);

    var pageContext = new PageContext
    {
        RequestContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext,
        Item = item
    };

    ContextService.Get().Push(pageContext);

    var pageDefinition = pageContext.PageDefinition;

    var getPageRenderingArgs = new GetPageRenderingArgs(pageDefinition);

    PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline("mvc.getPageRendering", getPageRenderingArgs);

    var rendering = getPageRenderingArgs.Result;

    var textWriter = new StringWriter();

    var renderRenderingArgs = new RenderRenderingArgs(rendering, textWriter);

    PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline("mvc.renderRendering", renderRenderingArgs);

    ContextService.Get().Pop<PageContext>();

    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Simply You can get the HTML of the page using Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage("provide url of item")

Comment: @durgar ExecuteWebPage() makes an actual HTTP request for the item. The method I proposed does not. Arbejdsglæde asked specifically for a solution that does not do a web request.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain I'm not sure why but this isn't working for me. I don't get any renderings returned even though I can see my renderings are there when debugging and looking at the PageContext object. Is it something to do with final renderings maybe?

Comment: @AdamSeabridge This should handle all the determination of which renderings to show based on personalization and all that. The `mvc.renderRendering` pipeline pipeline will handle then when given the page rendering. Are you getting a page rendering back after calling `mvc.getPageRendering`?

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain thanks for clarifying. Yes I get an page rendering back of type 'layout' and it looks ok but the child renderings are 0 and mvc.renderRendering returns nothing

Comment: @AdamSeabridge well, that looks like for whatever reason the renderings are getting there. Ensure everything is published, personalization rules are matching, etc. etc.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain I figured this out a few days after your last answer. It was a **** custom dynamic placeholders pipeline re-naming the placeholders when the same page was rendered multiple times (with different data). Sunk a lot of time into solving that one. Your code above works fine now...

Comment: @AdamSeabridge Excellent!

Comment: Hello @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain,

I can use your code, thank you. However I always have to switch context in cshtml rendering so that it could work with correct current item.

I want to add code to switch item context in your code. Tried and failed. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: @Tuananhcwrs Deleted previous comment as I misread. Please open a new question and reference this one.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked once created whole page in sitecore and added renderings and settings rendering parameters all programatically.
Getting and settings renderings on a page with code is possible. Have a look on something like this https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/get-sitecore-placeholders-and-rendering-hierarchy-from-a-sitecore-item/

You can make an ajax call and get html for a single rendering as a string.you can enhance below for your use case

```
        private static string GetHtmlFromPlaceholder(string placeholderKey, string returnHtml, PageContext pd, Item targetItem)
    {
        pd.Item = targetItem;
        var renderings = new List<Rendering>();
        var renderingCount = pd.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Context.Device, false).ToList();if (renderingCount.Count > 0)
        {
            renderings.AddRange(renderingCount.Select(r => new Rendering
            {
                RenderingItemPath = r.RenderingID.ToString(),
                Parameters = new RenderingParameters(r.Settings.Parameters),
                DataSource = r.Settings.DataSource,
                Placeholder = r.Placeholder,

            }));
            pd.PageDefinition.Renderings.AddRange(renderings);
            if (targetItem.TemplateID.ToString() == VirtualPDPPageTemplateGuid)
            {
                foreach (var r in renderings.Where(r => r.Placeholder.Contains("One-Column-Teaser") || r.Placeholder.Contains("Two-Column-Teaser")))
                {

                    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        PipelineService.Get()
                            .RunPipeline("mvc.renderRendering", new RenderRenderingArgs(r, stringWriter));
                        returnHtml += stringWriter.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var r in renderings.Where(r => r.Placeholder == placeholderKey))
                {

                    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        PipelineService.Get()
                            .RunPipeline("mvc.renderRendering", new RenderRenderingArgs(r, stringWriter));
                        returnHtml += stringWriter.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnHtml;
    }
```

Comment: yes, but I need just a result rendering - HTML data for full page.

Comment: I have updated something to get html of one rendering as a string above. you can enhance this for your use.