# Sitecore.Context.Item is Overwritten by RenderingContext.Current.Rendering

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I'm new to Sitecore FakeDb NUnit Testing. While testing the code, I found that

```
 Sitecore.Context.Item = null;
 RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource = fakeItem.ID.ToString();
```

Since the item is passed as Null, the corresponding data source overwrites the value.

Is this a Bug or, I'm getting it wrong here?

Comment: could you please show the (minimal) code required to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Sitecore FakeDb does not set the context item because depending on the scenario, you might or might not need it to be set.

If you need the context item not to be null, you can set it in *your test* using the `ContextItemSwitcher`:

```
using (var db = new Db { new DbItem("home") })
{
    var home = db.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
    using (new ContextItemSwitcher(home))
    {
        // Writes 'Context item = home'
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Context item = {0}", Context.Item.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there,

I'm following this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/is-it-possible-to-get-page-rendering-result-programmatically to run a whole pipeline and success with it.

However, I always have to have this "@Html.Sitecore().SwitchContextItem(myitem) " in the rendering before running the pipeline.

Is it possible to use ContextItemSwitcher in the helper code so that the "@Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem" will refer to myItem. I tried and failed. Thanks!