# Fetch all the page rendering results programatically(static & dynamic) and pass it to new sitecore item

Tags: presentation

I am trying to fetch all the renderings of a global item programatically and want to pass those renderings to another item without adding anything in the presentation

I have already tried `ItemRendering` which is working only for static renderings and is not working for dynamic renderings at all.

I have tried the below code in the page layout which works for static renderings, but is not fetching the dynamic renderings which are having a data source specified in those and have been using the dynamic placeholders.

```
@Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering("Item ID")
```

I have tried the code given in the below blog post.

[Is it possible to get page rendering result programmatically ?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/is-it-possible-to-get-page-rendering-result-programmatically)

When I debug this, it shows me all the rendering on the global item, however it is not returning all those renderings as a HTML where I want to display those.

Our main motive is to get the complete rendering result (static and dynamic) so that I can use it at different places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get page rendering result programmatically ?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/is-it-possible-to-get-page-rendering-result-programmatically)

Comment: @MarekMusielak No, I have tried this solution and this returns an empty value to me and not all the rendering values.

Comment: My other answer is the way to go. It should handle whatever is specified in the presentation details on the item, regardless.